# Jupyter Notebook special character

Tags: python, pandas

I am receiving data from CSV by using ipython.
[Here is an image of the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YZcA.png)

Here, I am trying to call the column of a pandas data frame labelled `(Among_’Yes’)Then,_where_do_you_meet_people_in_Seoul?`.

```
print('(Among_’Yes’)Then,_where_do_you_meet_people_in_Seoul?\n?')
output4 = []
d4 = data30.((Among_’Yes’)Then,_where_do_you_meet_people_in_Seoul?  \n).value_count()
```

However, it seems that the question mark(?) is not readable through ipython without any settings. In this case, what should I do for it to read through 
parenthesis, question marks and so on?

Comment: Is `data30` a pandas data frame?

Comment: yes... it is ..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the column incorrectly.  Try:

```
d4 = data30["(Among_’Yes’)Then,_where_do_you_meet_people_in_Seoul?"].value_counts()
```